# SQL Server - register Service Principle Name without service restart?

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, spn

I have a live SQL Server 2012 environment that had no SPN registered - this has previously not been an issue as Kerberos authentication wasn't required.  But now it is required.

I have configured everything correctly, but after these changes I want to ensure that SQL Server can register the SPN's successfully- preferably without a service restart as this is a live environment.

Is there a way of doing this?

P.S. I know I can register the SPN's manually, but I want to make certain that they can be registered automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Quick answer

#### Question:

> I have configured everything correctly, but after these changes I want to ensure that SQL Server can register the SPN's successfully- preferably without a service restart as this is a live environment.
>
> **Is there a way of doing this?**

#### Answer:

No.

### Explanation

From the official documentation [Register a Service Principal Name for Kerberos Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-2017)

> A Service Principal Name (SPN) must be registered with Active Directory, which assumes the role of the Key Distribution Center in a Windows domain. The SPN, after it is registered, maps to the Windows account that started the SQL Server instance service. **If the SPN registration has not been performed or fails, the Windows security layer cannot determine the account associated with the SPN, and Kerberos authentication will not be used.**

and

> If the server cannot automatically register the SPN, the SPN must be registered manually. See [Manual SPN Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-2017#Manual).

and further down in the section **Automatic SPN Registration** you can find

> **When an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine starts, SQL Server tries to register the SPN for the SQL Server service.** When the instance is stopped, SQL Server tries to unregister the SPN. For a TCP/IP connection the SPN is registered in the format MSSQLSvc/:.Both named instances and the default instance are registered as MSSQLSvc, relying on the  value to differentiate the instances.

### Summary

The SQL Server Service essentially regsisters the SPN on service start automatically. If you cannot start the SQL Server Service then you will have to perform this task manually.

### Considerations

Ensure the service account that start the SQL Server Service is allowed to read and write SPNs.

> To do this, you must grant the following access control settings for the SQL Server service account in the Active Directory directory service:
>
> - Read servicePrincipalName
> - Write servicePrincipalName

<sup>***Reference:*** [How to use Kerberos authentication in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/319723/how-to-use-kerberos-authentication-in-sql-server) (Microsoft Support)</sup>

Comment: As I was expecting, but was hoping otherwise...

Comment: I know, because I'm currently fighting for `Read servicePrincipalName` and `Write servicePrincipalName` permissions at my current company. Once the services have been cycled during a maintenance window, everything should be better. You could test beforehand with a test instance. Assign the rights to the service account and then cycle the service. You should then find a Service Principal Name under the service account by issuing: `setspn -l <DOMAIN>\<ACCOUNT>` (Replace <DOMAIN> and <ACCOUNT> with the corresponding service account)